# Express application with one API(route) which takes fullName as query parameter and splits it to firstName and lastName as output

Tags: express

I got a route /name which takes fullName as query parameter and gives firstName and lastName as output

```
app.get('/name', (req, res) => {

    req.query.fullName = fullName;

    let firstName = fullName.split(" ").slice(0).join(' ');
    let lastName = fullName.split(" ").slice(-1).join(' ');
    res.send(firstName, lastName);

});
```

But I cannot catch the request and modify it. It's returning ReferenceError: fullName is not defined

if input is `/name/fullName=john doe` then the respond should be

```
{'firstName':'john', 'lastName':'doe'}
```

Comment: Use this one `/name?fullName=john doe`

Answer (score 0):

`req.query.fullName = fullName;` is a wrong syntax. The correct syntax should be `const fullName = req.query.fullName;`. I made some improvement to you code.

```
app.get('/name', (req, res) => {

    const fullName = req.query.fullName;

    const [firstName, lastName] = fullName.trim().split(" ")

    res.status(200).json({firstName, lastName});

});
```

Also, you request input should be `/name?fullName=john doe`

Hope this helps